# Server side rendering with Riot.js: Passing opts.foo to this.foo in tag

Tags: riot.js

I am having problems with server side rending using Riot.

In my handler, I pass my foo object into my bar tag with something very similar to this:

```
reply(riot.render(bar, { foo: foo }));
```

This is a copy of my simple bar tag:

```
<bar>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>{ foo }</h1>

    this.foo = opts.foo
    console.log(this.foo)
</bar>
```

When I point my browser to the relevant path, 'TEST' is visible but foo is not. My console.log(foo) works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on a similar setup

```
<bar>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h1>{ opts.foo }</h1>
    console.log(opts.foo)
</bar>
```

I believe it works best to bind directly to the data object instead of setting it to another local variable